# Using 1 or more view model for register module (Sign in - Sign up - reset pass)?

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I'm working on an android project with MVVM + Data binding + Live data and I've some questions:

1. I have register module (Sign in - Sign up - reset pass) I'm asking is it better to use one view model for sign in & up or for every screen I should have view model?
2. If I take a user's info(mail- pass - name gender) should I use live string fields for them or use live user object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After some researches, it's better to use one viewModel for every screen
2. It's better to user live user object.